# How can I detect when a visitor leaves my page/site on our corporate intranet and where they're going?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

On our internal intranet, we have several embedded help files linked to from within our internal applications. I'm trying to determine whether or not the user is solely using our internal help files specific to the application or if they're visiting other resources such as our internal wiki, forums, newsletters, etc.. or possibly external sources.

I tried using onbeforeunload to return document.location.href, but it doesn't work as I need it to. For example, if the user is at internalhelp.company.com/page1.html and then leaves the page to go to internalwiki.company.com/wikipage1.php, the onbeforeunload returns internalhelp.company.com. I need it to return internalwiki.company.com.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems there is no easy way to tell when a user's session has ended - i.e. leave our site -  without making loose assumptions or making your content private. I could capture when users log out, capture inactivity within the browser window and assume the session has ended after 20 mins of inactivity, or capture the click event when users browse away using embedded links. 

None of which are very accurate. The best way to determine if a session ends would be a combination of those mentioned along with an event from the browser stating the URL browsed to is not in the same subdomain and/or TLD.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions.

Comment: You can make this an edit to your original question, rather than a comment. Click the [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4913540/edit) link at the lower left-hand corner of your question (or the one in this comment :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For privacy reasons, this is totally impossible.

If you're only interested in hyperlinks, you could add a click handler to all `<a>` tags which sends an AJAX request telling you that the link was clicked (or use a server-side interstitial page)

Comment: We already do that. I'm just trying to determine if the user leaves our site when they don't use one of the embedded links.  Any suggestions to determine when a session is ended without logging in/out?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this isn't possible to do with just JavaScript. For security reasons, JavaScript is sandboxed - in this case, it's confined to the page in which the script was loaded. You would have to use a browser extension, or something else that exists outside of the page scope.

Comment: Honestly, I don't care where they're going, as long as I can say with certainty they're no longer on my site. There should be a way to determine if a user leaves your domain without forcing them to login/logout, and without knowing where they're going. 


Any other suggestions? - Is there a way to capture this information in IIS?

Comment: @Joey: my recommendation would be to use a `window.unload` handler that sends an ajax request to your server, to inform you that they're changing pages. If that ajax request wasn't received immediately before (or after? I'm not sure of the order) another HTTP request for one of your pages, then they (probably) left your domain.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get *some* information, **IF** you have administrative/content control of the help site, is to wrap a external links with your own URL that can log the user clicking out.

For example, most/all external links on Facebook are of the form:

```
http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u={actual URL}
```

This way, Facebook can log the outclick.

If you don't have access to the links on the help site, you're stuck (for privacy reasons, by design -- otherwise anyone could write JavaScript that tracks what users are doing and where they're going).

Comment: Thank you, Payne for the suggestion. However, that would only work if we're embedding the link within our help page. Instead, we use an event listener to capture clicks (text and source) to the embedded links. If the user moves away from the help page without using one of the embedded links, we can't capture it to determine if the session has ended. 

I agree, any tracking/access to a user's browsing history is a security issue. But, why do browsers allow us to see where a user is coming from (in most cases), but we can't see where they're going. What's the difference in terms of privacy?

Comment: I'm only talking about where the user is going when they leave our help site. Not long term browsing activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookie for each page using javascript when they are loaded. Then when they are closed you can call `window.unload` function. In this function you can remove the cookie for that page. Then when there are no cookie user exits the site from browser. Can't it be implemented?